# Как сделать маркированный список в ряд, но с своей картинкой вместо маркера

Tags: css

Столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Нужно сделать маркированный список в горизонтальном положении, но при этом нужно, что бы показывалась картинка.
HTML

```
<ul class="first_level">
            <li>Чай</li>
            <li>Кофе</li>
            <li>Пакеты</li>
        </ul>
```

CSS

```
ul.first_level li {
    display: inline; /* Отображать как строчный элемент */
    margin-right: 105px; /* Отступ слева */
    list-style-image: url("img/list/ul_coffe.png");
}
```

С таким кодом, список отображается в ряд, но исчезают картинки. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например так

```css
ul.first_level li {
    background-image: url(../images/error.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

или [вот так](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-image)

Comment: Да! Это то, что нужно! Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Предыдущий ответ немного не подошёл. Т.к. изображение будет за текстом.

Ответ получился следующий:

```
ul.first_level li {
    display: inline;
    background: url("img/list/ul_coffe.png") no-repeat;
    line-height: 20px;

    margin: 25px;
    padding: 4px 105px 4px   20px;

}
```

Надеюсь, что кому-то это сэкономит пару часов жизни =)